# Overflow hidden with parent div in absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have a very specific requirement that is, the parent `div` is with `absolute:position` and child `div` with `absolute position` and in the parent `div` I have `overflow:hidden` so the extra `width` of the child `div` get hidden but this is not working, I know the parent `div` would have to be with `position:relative`, but as per the current structure of my code I cannot change the parent `div` `position` from `absolute` to `relative`, just wanted to know if there is a way to handle this?

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/f7zsmjmf/) of example, I want the light red box to be hidden under the parent `div` so the child `div` would be within parent.

Here is my code

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #666666;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 380px;
  background: #fecccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    Content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code, as per your requirement:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #666666;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed out to add `overflow:hidden` in `wrapper` class.

```css
.wrapper{position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px; width:400px; height:350px; background:#666666; padding:10px; overflow:hidden;}
.wrapper-inner{position:absolute; width:450px; height:380px; background:#fecccc;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="wrapper-inner">
     Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed but actually something wrong, as in my project code I have added overflow hidden, but its not working there...may be I think I should post that code here

Answer (score 0):

**Please check out my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hassaan39/601bLrnc/)**

```css
.wrapper{position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px; width:400px; height:350px; overflow:hidden; background:#666666; padding:10px;}
.wrapper-inner{position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; background:#fecccc; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="wrapper-inner">
     Content goes here Content goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes hereContent goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding your requirement, you don't want to see the child div extending outside the parent div. You mentioned `overflow:hidden`, but that does not actually exist in your fiddle.  Adding it to the `.wrapper` class does seem to accomplish what I think is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f7zsmjmf/2/)

css

```
.wrapper-inner {
  position: absolute; /* positioned wrt it parent */
  top:10px; /* account for 10px padding in parent */
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  /* width: 450px;
  height: 380px; */
  background: #fecccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the **`overflow:hidden`** in parent wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #666666;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.wrapper-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 380px;
  background: #fecccc;
}
```

In short, you had answered your own question! :)